# Is there a way to combine 2 LINQ2XML queries?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
var instructions = (from item in config.Elements("import")
select new
{
    name = item.Attribute("name").Value,
    watchFolder = item.Attribute("watchFolder").Value,
    root = item.Element("documentRoot").Value,
    DocumentNameDynamic = item.Element("documentName").Attribute("xpath").Value,
    DocumentNameStatic = item.Element("documentName").Attribute("static").Value,
    TemplateName = item.Element("template").Attribute("template").Value,
    Path = item.Element("path").Attribute("path").Value,
    fields = item.Element("fields").Elements()
}).SingleOrDefault();

var fields = from item in instructions.fields
select new
{
    xpath = item.Attribute("xpath").Value,
    FieldName = item.Attribute("FieldName").Value,
    isMultiValue = bool.Parse(item.Attribute("multiValue").Value)
};
```

Comment: In what way do you intend to combine these queries?  You just want a single query to generate the contents of `fields`? `instructions`? Both `instructions` and `fields`?  You you need the items of `fields` variable to be within the `fields` property within `instructions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work. I added the Select method to return the anonymous class.

```
var instructions = (from item in config.Elements("import")
select new
{
    name = item.Attribute("name").Value,
    watchFolder = item.Attribute("watchFolder").Value,
    root = item.Element("documentRoot").Value,
    DocumentNameDynamic = item.Element("documentName").Attribute("xpath").Value,
    DocumentNameStatic = item.Element("documentName").Attribute("static").Value,
    TemplateName = item.Element("template").Attribute("template").Value,
    Path = item.Element("path").Attribute("path").Value,
    fields = item.Element("fields").Elements().Select(item => new {
        xpath = item.Attribute("xpath").Value,
        FieldName = item.Attribute("FieldName").Value,
        isMultiValue = bool.Parse(item.Attribute("multiValue").Value)
    }
).SingleOrDefault();
```

If you don't want to use the Select Extension method, you can use LINQ syntax. Here is an example of this.

```
var instructions = (from item in config.Elements("import")
select new
{
    name = item.Attribute("name").Value,
    watchFolder = item.Attribute("watchFolder").Value,
    root = item.Element("documentRoot").Value,
    DocumentNameDynamic = item.Element("documentName").Attribute("xpath").Value,
    DocumentNameStatic = item.Element("documentName").Attribute("static").Value,
    TemplateName = item.Element("template").Attribute("template").Value,
    Path = item.Element("path").Attribute("path").Value,
    fields = from e in item.Element("fields").Elements()
             select new {
                 xpath = item.Attribute("xpath").Value,
                 FieldName = item.Attribute("FieldName").Value,
                 isMultiValue = bool.Parse(item.Attribute("multiValue").Value)
             } // End of inner select statement
} // End of outer select statement
).SingleOrDefault();
```